# Excel: VBA Grey out unused areas

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a VBA code which can automatically grey out unused areas in Excel, similar to 'page break view', except that it doesn't show the pagenumber (and line breaks)?

I know the function page break view, but the pagenumbers are disturbing and can't be hidden. Let me know!

Thanks, both solutions below worked!

Comment: Fill the entire sheet with gray and then fill the parts you're using to white.  (Yeah, kinda like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49587362/8112776))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use:

```
Sub Greyout()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
            With .Range(.Range("A1"), .UsedRange).Interior
                .Pattern = -4142
                .PatternColorIndex = -4142
                .ThemeColor = -4142
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just hide everything outside of the worksheet's UsedRange property.

```
Sub hideUnused()
    With Worksheets("sheet8")
        .Range(.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1), .Columns(.Columns.Count)).Hidden = True
        .Range(.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1), .Rows(.Rows.Count)).Hidden = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The actual color is going to depend on your Excel application's palette.